# kapt doesn't resolve protobuf-generated classes

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, protocol-buffers, kapt

I get such error during the build:

```
e: /Users/some/path/SomeClass.java:86: error: cannot find symbol 
e:       
e:     static ConnectionType getConnectionType(Context context) { 
e:            ^ 
e:   symbol:   class ConnectionType 
e:   location: class SomeClass
```

Where `ConnectionType` is class generated by protobuf. So it looks like kapt doesn't resolve generated classes.

**What I've tried?**

At first I added `kotlin-apt` plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Then I added brotobuf-generated classes to source set:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
}
```

And also I want to have generated classes before kapt starts it's work. So I order gradle tasks this way:

```
afterEvaluate {
    def protoTasks = []
    tasks.each { task ->
        if (task.name.contains('proto') || task.name.contains('Proto')) {
            protoTasks.push(task)
        }
    }

    tasks.each { task ->
        if (task.name.startsWith('kapt')) {
            task.dependsOn protoTasks
        }
    }
}
```

But all these things don't help, I still got the same error. How to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure, that the classes are generated? So can you see the `class` file for e.g. `ConnectionType` in your class-output folder?

Comment: @guenhter I can see just `.java` files, but not `.class` files.

Comment: Can you see the `SomeClass.class` file of your class?

Comment: I guess it would be helpful if you append these options to your gradle command `./gradlew .... --info --stacktrace` and put the whole output in here.

Comment: @guenhter now I noticed that gradle skips `:generateDebugAndroidTestProto` as it has no source files and no previous output files.

Comment: Maybe you still can post your output of the gradle command with `--info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by wrong path to protobuf source set. I had to use correct flavor name in it, like:

```
sourceSets {
    // ...
    main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/flavor/java'
}
```

instead of

```
sourceSets {
    // ...
    main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify the `sourceDir`, if you want do so, you must specify all possible path which the Java file (maybe from Protobuf) or Kotlin file contained. In fact, the default `sourceDir` contains all possible paths.